# detect geode, fire eagle, or google gear installed on browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, geolocation, google-gears

is there any demo on how to detect geode ,fire eagle, google gear installed on user browsers and get user location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a brief [page explaining different ways for a developer to obtain a user's location](http://npdoty.name/location/#developer), including IP geolocation, the W3C Geolocation API and reverse geocoding.

It's possible that you might want to detect [Geode](http://labs.mozilla.com/blog/2008/10/introducing-geode/), [Loki](http://www.loki.com/why/demoapps/simple) or [Google Gears](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/api%5Fgeolocation.html) geolocation as well (although I think those are likely to be phased out once the W3C API is settled on). [Ajaxian has built a shim](http://ajaxian.com/archives/navigatorgeolocation-using-the-w3c-geolocation-api-today) that will abstract out queries to W3C, Gears and Google ClientLocation.

Finally, [Fire Eagle](http://fireeagle.yahoo.net/) is just a location broker -- you can install [a Firefox plugin for Fire Eagle](http://fireeagle.yahoo.net/firefox), but that still won't provide websites with access to the user's Fire Eagle location.  (That would be cool though, I hope they're working with Mozilla on that).